# 100% CPU usage caused by upowerd

Tags: 22.04, thinkpad, ubuntu-gnome

On my Thinkpad (L490) notebook I have installed Ubuntu 22.04. Except for Docker it is basically the default setup of Ubuntu desktop.

Periodically I have a CPU utilization of all cores of 100%. Looking into top shows me, that the upowerd process has something to do with it. I am not sure how can I figure out what causes the problem and why.

My notebook is powered through USB-C by the monitor and I am using a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse.

I have read in other threads that an IPhone or IPad can cause these issues, but I am not using any of these devices.

Has someone a hint for me? Which logs can help to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you maybe include a screenshot of `top` or `htop` so we can see the same as you?

Comment: Are you running docker when the CPU usage hits 100% ?

Comment: By powering the laptop the way you do you are basically using it the same as an Iphone or Ipad. Have you tired the suggests you saw for the other devices?